# How do I upgrade libxml2 to version 2.9.9 in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos

My step:

Download:

```
# wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz
```

Unpacking the archive:

```
# tar -zxvf libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz
```

Move into the directory:

```
# cd libxml2-2.9.9/
```

Doing something weird:

```
# ./configure && make && make install
```

This command returns an error:

```
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/root/libxml2-2.9.9':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Command: `php -i | grep libxml` produces the following result:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
libxml
libxml2 Version => 2.9.1
OLDPWD => /root/libxml2-2.9.9
_SERVER["OLDPWD"] => /root/libxml2-2.9.9
```

Command: `yum update-to libxml2-2.9.9` - not working.

Answer (score 1):

> configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Solution : `# yum install gcc-c++` ... I.e. installing both gcc and g++ will also install all the packages which make `gcc` work fully.

Note : `./configure` alone will install to /usr/local/, and **not update** the current version 2.9.1 . Required is

```
tar xvf libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz
cd libxml2-2.9.9/
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
make
# make install
```

Comment: Sorry sir. I am a beginning linux user. I have installed PHP 7.3.9 remi. Could you describe the upgrade process, literally step by step (by command)? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Looks like a new question. »» upgrade process «« : Is it about `php` ? Or ?

Comment: We are talking about upgrading libxml2 to version 2.9.9. On CentOS 7 and PHP 7.3.9. I, to my shame, do not understand how to do it... Thank you sir

Comment: libxml2-2.9.9 : See the edited answer. .... php-7.3.9-1.el7.remi http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/remi/enterprise/7Server/php73/x86_64/repoview/ : That's a new topic → Please start a new thread about php.

Comment: I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772929/how-to-upgrade-libxml2-to-version-2-9-9-in-php-7-3-9-in-centos