# How to upgrade libxml2 to version 2.9.9 in PHP-7.3.9 in CentOS?

Tags: php, centos7

I have a server on CentOS 7 which I have installed PHP version 7.3.9 (# yum-y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm). In it (in PHP) have an old version of libxml2 (2.9.1). How do I update this library to version 2.9.9?

I do so:

```
# yum install python-devel

# yum install gcc-c++

# cd /usr/local/

# yum install libxml2-devel

# wget http://xmlsoft.org/sources/libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz

# tar xvf libxml2-2.9.9.tar.gz

# cd libxml2-2.9.9/

# ./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64

# make

# make install
```

But the libxml2 version is not updated (2.9.1)...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why **exactly** do you want to do so? Why not use the regular versions from the package repositories?

Comment: @NicoHaase I need the latest version of xPath

Answer (score 1):

If you rebuild such critical library, you have to rebuild everything which use it (thus, including php)

Comment: I don't know how to do it